Understanding GSM FCCH (Frequency Correction Burst)
I would like to apologize for some inaccuracies,
I am a newbie in digital signal processing. I do not understand how FCCH works and is arranged. After GMSK demodulation I get a sequence of 148 zeros (including tail 0 bits at the beginning and at the end), according to the GSM 05.02 [5.2.4] specification.
I understand, I should add 1625/24 (~67.708 kHz) to the current channel frequency (in my case 938.4 mHz + 67.708 kHz), but after that, I no longer receive either FCCH or SCH (and I successfully receive the latter if I do not add the frequency).
I also used the kalibrate tool from github, which most likely searches for the correct frequency offset, according to the output there, the channel values ​​are several times smaller (for example + 10.858 kHz). I am interested in when FCCH is used and why the official documentation states 1625/24 kHz?
